# Creating an array which assigns answers options as either true or false in setchoices for Google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I would like some advice on a problem I am having. I would like to make a self-grading multiple-choice quiz that is set-up in a Google Sheet. I would like some questions to have more than one answer and therefore I need to make an array of choices whereby each answer is assigned true or false dependent on whether it appears in the answers array. However, with the code I have at the moment, the answers are showing correctly as correct in the Google form quiz but all answers are repeated 4 x for each question which means my for loops are incorrect but I can't, for the life of me, see what mistake I have made. Any help would be great, thank you!

```
//make Multiple-Choice question
function makeMultipleQ(data) { //data- a row of spreadsheet dataRange
 var question = data[2]
 var questionNumber = data[0]
 var answer = data[9]
 var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem(); //form to add choice
 item.setTitle(questionNumber + '. ' + question)
 var trimmedData = data.filter(function(str) {
   return /\S/.test(str)
  })
  var slicedData = [1,2,3,4]
  var answers = [1,2,6,7,8,9]
  var choices = []; //array of choices
  for (var i = 0; i < slicedData.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < answers.length; k++){
      if (slicedData[i] == answers[k]) {
        choices.push(item.createChoice(answers[k],true))
          }
      else {
        choices.push(item.createChoice(slicedData[i],false)); //wrong answer pushed to choices
    }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(choices)
  item.setChoices(choices); //set the choices array to this itemQ
}
```

This is the output on the Google form:

[image: Google form output as the code stands]

[image: This is the Google sheet]

Comment: Could you please share an example spreadsheet to visualize how your questions are ordered to make the troubleshooting process easier? And I don't understand your ```slicedData``` array. Are those the questions?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I have attached the Google sheet to the post. The sliced data is so that I can separate off the question options and question answers and then compare these arrays to give the option a true or false assignemtn for correct or incorrect. However, to play around I have changed the arrays to include dummy number data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Unnecessary nesting of loops. For each `i` in the outer loop, inner loop will run to completion for each `k`.

#### Solution:

- Use `indexOf` to check the inner `answers` array  instead of looping again

#### Snippet:

```
if (answers.indexOf(slicedData[i]) !== -1) {//k loop removed
    choices.push(item.createChoice(slicedData[i],true))
}
```